# Using jQuery offset to position <div>, but it looks like the postion is incremented

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the code below to reposition the div in a click event handler. The first time the div is shown where expected (50, 50), but the second time the position is (100, 100).

I want to display the div at the location defined in the offset (in my app this is done though a calculation, for simplicity I've hard-coded (50, 50) here.

```
$("#cd_wheredropdown").offset({ top: 50, left: 50});
```

I've created a jsfiddle which shows the exact same problem:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2va1t7e/)

I've simplyfied the code as much as possible to isolate the problem, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

html:

```
<div id="cd_wheredropdown"></div>

<p class="cd_hasWhere">Click me</p>
```

css:

```
#cd_wheredropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 60;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: none;
}
```

jquery:

```
var whereDialogClass = function () {
    $(".cd_hasWhere").bind( "click", this.doOpen);
    $("#cd_wheredropdown").bind( "click", this.doClose);
}

whereDialogClass.prototype.doClose = function() {
    $("#cd_wheredropdown").fadeOut();
}

whereDialogClass.prototype.doOpen = function(event) {
    $("#cd_wheredropdown").offset({ top: 50, left: 50});
    $("#cd_wheredropdown").fadeIn();
}

var whereDialog = new whereDialogClass();
```

Comment: Just use `.css()` instead -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/f2va1t7e/1/

Comment: That does seems to do the trick. Thanks. Still wierd why the offset() function has such a strange effect.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code will help. This happens because When you click on once, it adds the `offset` to the `<div>`, instead of simply setting to the specified offset. Clicking again, you reactivates the function again.

For good result, Use `CSS` and avoid using offset.

```
whereDialogClass.prototype.doClose = function() {
    $("#cd_wheredropdown").fadeOut();
    $("#cd_wheredropdown").offset({ top: 0, left: 0}); // reposition the div
}
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f2va1t7e/2/)

Though fadeout effect seems little weired.

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but the funky fadeout effect makes it not very usable. It may lead to a better understanding to what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a "bug" in `offset()` where it gets the elements current position to calculate the offset to set.

When the element is hidden, as in `display : none`, the elements position is returned to `offset()` as zero every time, because the element has no position, it's hidden, but in reality the position is `50px` from the top and the left, as that's what was set on the first click, so it just keeps compounding.

The solution would be to just use `css()` to position the element instead

```
$("#cd_wheredropdown").css({ top: 50, left: 50});
```

Comment: That may just be the case. I'll go with the css solution. Thanks.